# Cancelling jQuery POST to ASP.Net WebMethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, ajax, webmethod

I am working on a web application which queries MS-SQL real-time via a dot net webmethod like so:

**jQuery**

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "page.aspx/SearchMatchingRecords",
    data: "{ company:'" + company + "', country:'" + country + "', id: <%= Request.QueryString["id"] %>}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      if (data != "") {
          for (var post in data) {
              var results = data[post];

              var output = '<table ... headers... etc';

              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
              {
                   output += "<tr><td>";
                   output += #DATA#
                   output += "</td></tr>";
              }

              output += '</tbody></table>';

              $('[id="fsMatchingRecords"]').append(output);
                      }
                    };
                    return false;
                 }
               })
              }

              $('[id$="BtnVerify"]').click(function () {
              xhr.abort();
              });
```

This talks to **WebMethod**

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<MatchingRecord> SearchMatchingRecords(string company, string country, int id)
{        
    SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString);

    objConn.Open();

    List<MatchingRecord> mRecords = new List<MatchingRecord>();

    SqlCommand objCmd2 = new SqlCommand("Page_Matching_Records", objConn);
    objCmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    objCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company_1", HttpUtility.UrlDecode(company));
    objCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country_2", country);
    objCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_3", id);
    SqlDataReader objDr = objCmd2.ExecuteReader();

    int i = 0;

    if (objDr.HasRows)
    {
        while (objDr.Read())
        {
            mRecords.Add(new MatchingRecord(
                Convert.ToInt32(objDr["id"]), 
                objDr["Rest of Data"]
                ))
            );
        }
    }

    objConn.Close();

    return mRecords;
}
```

The webmethod returns results which are then appended to the DOM in realtime- really happy with the way this operates.

The issue is that, when a generic/vague search term is passed through to the database, the query can sometimes take a while to return the data. What I am trying to do at the bottom of the jQuery snippet - is cancel the XMLHttpRequest using **abort**.

During this time that the page is waiting for the return, the user is unable to interact with the page. Link buttons and ASP buttons don't respond but do queue for the return and then fire as soon as possible. This is causing problems.

The scenario means that simply putting an SQL timeout or blacklisting certain troublesome search terms would be difficult to manage and so the ability for the user to cancel the request is crucial.

What have I neglected here? I've seen many use this method to cancel jQuery POST method. Could it be that there is another layer to this request because the server thread is waiting for SQL server to respond? Is there any way to simply ignore it?